# I need help understanding javascript ||. Is it a Logical 'OR' or not

Tags: javascript

Sorry if asked and answered, but all my searches are returning information about logical OR and doesn't clarify the situation.

I fully understand the '|' vs '||' in most languages, but this is throwing me for a loop. I've been exposed to javascript, but I know very little about it and the following code confuses me.

```
:
a = a || document;

// HANDLE: $(function)
// Shortcut for document ready
if ( jQuery.isFunction(a) )
    return new jQuery(document)[ jQuery.fn.ready ? "ready" : "load" ]( a );
:
```

In most cases, I understand "a = a || document;" to return 'true' if either is valid or false if both are null, 0, etc...

I have the same problem with the following code.

```
:
jQuery.fn.height = function() {
if ( this[0] == window )
    return self.innerHeight ||
        jQuery.boxModel && document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
        document.body.clientHeight;

if ( this[0] == document )
    return Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight );

return this._height(arguments[0]);};
:
```

How does the following result in a height value? or Does it?

```
:
    if ( this[0] == window )
    return self.innerHeight ||
        jQuery.boxModel && document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
        document.body.clientHeight;
:
```

Comment: Please see http://addyosmani.com/blog/exploring-javascripts-logical-or-operator/ and it works the same as `&&`

Comment: All my searches resulted in a boolean (only) explanation, but not clearing the muddy water (for me). I'm just used to boolean results only and varying from that led me to questioning what was going on. p.s.w.g, and a few others, have shown me the light. Many thanks to all for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators):

> `expr1 || expr2`
>
> (Logical OR) Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to `true`; otherwise, returns `expr2`.  Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns `true` if either operand is `true`; if both are `false`, returns `false`.

It will evaluate the left side of the expression first, and if the result can be converted to `true`, it stops there. Otherwise, it will evaluate and return the right side of the expression.

So in other words, it's can be used as a kind control structure as well as a Boolean OR operator. It can be used a shorthand for something like this

```
var result = <expr1>;
if (!result) result = <expr2>;
```

The documentation goes on to provide some helpful examples:

```
var o1 =  true || true;     // t || t returns true
var o2 = false || true;     // f || t returns true
var o3 =  true || false;    // t || f returns true
var o4 = false || (3 == 4); // f || f returns false
var o5 = "Cat" || "Dog";    // t || t returns Cat
var o6 = false || "Cat";    // f || t returns Cat
var o7 = "Cat" || false;    // t || f returns Cat
```

Comment: Many thanks. The majority of my experience with | vs || is in C\C++ and HDLs where it only returns a boolean (AFAIK or have every seen). I assumed it was returning the value like "Cat", but have never really used it like that and assumptions lead to trouble, plus I couldn't find any documentation on it. Many thanks to the info and the link.

Comment: @Lee Yeah, strongly typed languages like C\C++ have strict of rules about how and where you can use operators like this. JS is much more weakly typed, which is why it acts more like a control structure than a true operator.

Answer (score 2):

`||` is a *lazy* [logical OR operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.11). Both expressions are converted to bool values via [`ToBoolean`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2); being lazy, the `b` expression is *only* evaluated if `ToBoolean(a)` is false.

*The result of `a || b` is always the value of either the `a` or `b` expression*, as per this TTL:

```
ToBoolean(a)   ToBoolean(b)      a || b
------------   ---------------   -------------------------
true           (Not Evaluated)   a (ToBoolean(a) == true)
true           (Not Evaluated)   a (ToBoolean(a) == true)
false          true              b (ToBoolean(b) == true)
false          false             b (ToBoolean(b) == false)
```

The [`ToBoolean`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2) function determines the ["truthiness"](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) of a value. "Truthy" values are:

- Finite numbers, except for 0
- strings of length > 0
- true
- All objects, including empty arrays (`null` and `undefined` are *not* objects!)

On the other hand, `|` is a [bitwise OR operation](http://es5.github.io/#x11.10). It *eagerly* converts the operands via [`ToInt32`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.5) and performs the bitwise OR operation. The result of `|` is always a number in the range `[-2^31, 2^31)`, which need not be either of the input values.

---

Looking at the "clever" code (the added parenthesis do not change the precedence), we start with:

```
return self.innerHeight ||
    (jQuery.boxModel && document.documentElement.clientHeight) ||
    document.body.clientHeight;
```

Which, with substitution (this is paper substitute as using a variable assignment would force evaluation), looks like:

```
return a || b || c;   // or, return (a || b) || c
```

This say "return the first 'truthy' value", lazily evaluated.

There is a bit of added complexity as `b` is `boxModel && documentElement.clientHeight`, but `&&` works the same way as `||` (excepting the TTL) and returns the evaluation of one of the input expressions. In this case that means that `b` is only truthy (and thus the result of `a || b || c` where `a` is not truthy) when `boxModel` is truthy (i.e. `true`) *and* `clientHeight` is truthy (i.e. not 0): if there is a truthy result for `b`, then it must be the value of `clientHeight`.

Looking at the compressed TTL might also help, where "*" means "don't care" and T/F represent Truthy/Falsey values (as per ToBoolean):

```
a  = self.innerHeight
b1 = jQuery.boxModel
b2 = document.documentElement.clientHeight
c  = document.body.clientHeight;

a      b1     b2     b (b1 && b2)   c      a || b || c
----   ----   ----   ------------   ----   -----------
T      *      *      *              *      a  (T)
F      T      T      b2 (T)         *      b2 (T)
F      T      F      b2 (F)         *      c  (T or F)
F      F      *      b1 (F)         *      c  (T or F)
```

---

Because this can get complicated, as shown above, I usually avoid such constructs where `||` and `&&` operators are intertwined in an expression which is used for more than it's computed "boolean" truthiness.

Answer (score 0):

The link in the comment is good, but put simply in your first example:

In most cases, I understand "a = a || document;" to return 'true' if either is valid or false if both are null, 0, etc...

That actually reads as:

Set "a" to "a" if "a" is "truthy"... if "a" is not "truthy" then set "a" to "document".

This is often used as a way of initializing a variable only if its not already initialized... or also for initializing a property of an object if its not already set... for example

```
myObj[key] = myObj[key] || {};
```

The other great thing about || and && is that they "early out"... in that they stop as soon as they can... so you can imagine this:

a = a || b || c || d

if a is already set to something it only gets this far "a = a"... if "a" was falsy then it would check b... etc...

So they are nice if you remember to take advantage of the fact that they bail out early.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example might help you can understand it:

```
var objOne = true, objTwo = false, objOR;

objOR = objOne || objTwo; // true
```

So now `objOR` only equal false when both of `objOne` and `objTwo` are false. In your case, I think you need a bracket between 2 clause && and ||. Like this:

```
(jQuery.boxModel && document.documentElement.clientHeight) ||
        document.body.clientHeight;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that addresses the question. OP understand Boolean operations, but not how this operator works with non-Booleans or as control structures in JS statements like `a = a || document`.

Answer (score 0):

|| in JavaScript is unlike C-like languages.  The value of a sequence of || operators is the first operand that can evaluate to true (this is commonly known as a truthy value).  There are a few values that are not considered truthy (empty string, null, undefined, 0, NaN, false).  Everything else is truthy

For example, `var x = false || undefined || 1 || "5";` evaluates to 1.  false and undefined are non-truthy, "5" is disregarded as the expression evaluation doesn't "get that far" and stops at 1.

For more information, consult these links.

http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

http://helephant.com/2008/12/09/javascript-null-or-default-operator/